# Spring RequestBody Mapping maps all attributes to null values

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, request-mapping

i have the following RESTfull method :

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/budgetLines",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public void create(@RequestBody BudgetLine budgetLine) {
    System.out.println("Before Persisting in the repository " + budgetLine);
    budgetLineRepository.save(budgetLine);
}
```

I'am consuming this method inside a web application, i checked using the network  analysis tool (in the web developper tool of chrome) that the object sended is valid (all attribute except the id were set with a valid value), but then the object passed to the repository contains only null attributes.

here is an example body :

```
{
    "Name":"testLabel",
    "Label":"testName",
    "AnnualBudget":9000
}
```

the class BudgetLine is defined as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_BUDGETLINE")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class BudgetLine implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "label")
    private String Label;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String Name;

    @Column(name = "annual_budget", precision=10, scale=2)
    private BigDecimal AnnualBudget;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "budgetLine")
    @JsonIgnore
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Report> reportss = new HashSet<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return Label;
    }

    public void setLabel(String Label) {
        this.Label = Label;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String Name) {
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public BigDecimal getAnnualBudget() {
        return AnnualBudget;
    }

    public void setAnnualBudget(BigDecimal AnnualBudget) {
        this.AnnualBudget = AnnualBudget;
    }

    public Set<Report> getReportss() {
        return reportss;
    }

    public void setReportss(Set<Report> Reports) {
        this.reportss = Reports;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        BudgetLine budgetLine = (BudgetLine) o;

        if (id != null ? !id.equals(budgetLine.id) : budgetLine.id != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BudgetLine{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", Label='" + Label + "'" +
                ", Name='" + Name + "'" +
                ", AnnualBudget='" + AnnualBudget + "'" +
                '}';
    }

    public BudgetLine() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Try with first letter in lowercase for parameters, `name`, `label` and `annualBudget` in request body.

Comment: Wow, that was it thank you, never crossed my mind

Comment: Great, I've added it as an answer since it helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with first letter in lowercase for parameters

```
{
    "name":"testLabel",
    "label":"testName",
    "annualBudget":9000
}
```

Spring relies heavily on standard Java naming conventions, so I suggest you also follow them. In your example, you should name your class fields with lowercased first letter.